# get run time changed tag attribute in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
$("#2").attr({"data-sort-code":003});

function callfun()
{
  
var code=$("#2").data("sort-code");
  
  $get('lblName').value=code;
alert(code);

  
}
</script>

<html>
  <body>
        <ul>
   <li><a id="1" data-sort-code="001">Comapny 1</a>
 <ul>
    <li><a id="2" data-sort-code="001001"> Company 1.1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a id="3" data-sort-code="001002"> Company 1.1</a>
    </li>

 </ul>
   </li>
   <li> <a id="4" data-sort-code="002"></a>
   </li>
</ul>
    
    <input type="button" onclick="callfun();" value="Click" />
    <input type="label" id="lblName"/>
    </body>
  </html>
```

```
<ul>
   <li><a id="1" data-sort-code="001">Comapny 1</a>
    <ul>
       <li><a id="2" data-sort-code="001001"> Company 1.1</a>
       </li>
       <li><a id="3" data-sort-code="001002"> Company 1.1</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li> <a id="4" data-sort-code="002">Company 2</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

If i change the sort code of id=2 to 003 in runtime 
as follows,

```
$("#2").attr({"data-sort-code":003});
```

its changes at run time, but in the same run time if try to fetch the sort code
as follows,

```
var code=$("#2").data("sort-code");
alert(code);
```

alert msg still shows as "001001"

can any one tell me how to get the sort code at run time.

Comment: Can you make fiddle for this? I think it should work.

Comment: as i'm new to stack overflow i dont know making fiddle:(

Comment: You can make Running snippet in your question. Its an option right side of image icon.

Comment: did you tried with `$("#2").attr("data-sort-code","003");`?

Comment: You are trying to access the DOM before it has loaded, so `$("#2")` will return an empty jQuery set, thus not changing the `data-sort-code`.

Answer (score 1):

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vakj714L/)

replace

```
$("#2").attr({"data-sort-code":003});
```

with

```
$("#2").attr("data-sort-code","003");
```

anyways `003` will become `3` unless enclosed in quotes

also check with

```
var code=$("#2").attr("data-sort-code");
alert(code);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will fix it. Just use data function in both the places. set it with

```
$("#2").data("sort-code","003");
```

and get it with

```
$("#2").data("sort-code")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the data variable as

```
$("#2").attr({"data-sort-code":003});
```

than use:

```
code=$("#2").attr("data-sort-code");
alert(code);
```

and if you are using

```
var code=$("#2").data("sort-code");
alert(code);
```

than set it by using

```
$("#2").data("sort-code","003");
```